# comparar array con enum angular

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

tengo un array de strings que quiero comparar con un enum y crear un array nuevo solo con el valor de ese enum si mi string de array es la clave del enum me explico:

```
JavaScript,
 PHP, 
TypeScript,
 Java,
 TypeScript, 
HTML, 
Python
```

este es el array resultado de un map que le hice a mi servicio entonces en mi enum tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
export enum colores{


  TypeScript= '#2b7489',
  PureBasic= '#5a6986',

}
```

es mucho mas largo mi enum pero solo coloco este para hacerme entender en lo que quiero, y es como tengo "TypeScript" crear un nuevo array solo con el valor que corresponda en mi enum que seria '#2b7489' porque es lo que espera mi chartjs para la grafica.

he intentado recorrer el con foreach pero al enum no se puede al parecer, no entiendo como puedo hacer esa comparacion.